# AngularJS - filter data with 'true' attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-filters

I am using AngularJS, and i have joined subdocuments('orderfood' from below JSON) and got sum of its quantity of my JSON data, under `orderfood` i have `confirm` attribute. i would like to filter only the data which has the value `placed` in `confirm` attribute. my [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QGID5kHoCzT03ia90St4?p=preview)

**Result i got**

```
3 quantities of V 4 Vanilla should be prepared
3 quantities of Power cut should be prepared
```

**Expected Result**

```
2 quantities of V 4 Vanilla should be prepared
3 quantities of Power cut should be prepared
```

**JSON**

```
[{
"_id": "56e3bff0e9932ca6425e6f65",
"orderfood": [
  {
  "qty": "2",
  "confirm": "placed",
  "name": "V 4 Vanilla"
  }
],
"name": "Rohit",
"created": "2016-03-12T07:06:24.424Z"
},
{
"_id": "56e3bd5bc3791b973c048804",
"user": null,
"__v": 10,
"orderfood": [
  {
  "qty": "1",
  "confirm": "cancelled",
  "name": "V 4 Vanilla"
  },
  {
  "qty": "3",
  "confirm": "placed",
  "name": "Power cut"
  }
],
"name": "Rohit",
"created": "2016-03-12T06:55:23.244Z"
}];
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getOrderFoods = function() {
var orderfood = [];

$scope.reduce= function(data){
   return data.reduce(function(previousValue,
   currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + parseInt(currentValue.qty);
}, 0);
}

angular.forEach($scope.orders, function(order) {
  angular.forEach(order.orderfood, function(orderfoo) {
    if (orderfood.indexOf(orderfoo) == -1) {
      orderfood.push(orderfoo);
    }
  })
});
return orderfood;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in getOrderFoods() | groupBy:'name'">
  <p><span>{{reduce(data)}}</span> quantities of <span>{{key}}</span> should be prepared </p>
</div>
```

my [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QGID5kHoCzT03ia90St4?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the condition as a filter in your `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,data) in getOrderFoods() | filter: {confirm: 'placed'} | groupBy:'name'">
```

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/honH9lGojE8Qh8J06GZY?p=preview)